# nvd3 disabling tooltip delay on show/hide

Tags: tooltip, delay, nvd3.js

[http://jsfiddle.net/kaliatech/PGyKF/](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html)

This example has a continuously updating nvd3 line graph.
By default nvd3 introduces a delay in showing the tooltip during a mouse hover.

Is there anyway to disable this?

Answer (score 5):

The controls for adjusting delays and transitions are in css files

Edited nv.d3.css

```
.nvtooltip {
...
...
transition: opacity 0ms linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 0ms linear;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0ms linear;

transition-delay: 0ms;
-moz-transition-delay: 0ms;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0ms;
...
...
}
```

Worked!